# How to implement requirejs in master and child page.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, requirejs

I have a master page in .net framwork in which i have used `require.js` as bellow.

```
 <script data-main="../../Scripts/Shared/_MaintenanceTemplateApp" src="../../Scripts/require.js"></script>
```

In `_MaintenanceTemplateApp.js` I have `requirejs.config({});` in this I have used `"baseUrl"`, `"Path"` and '"shim"' then following code is there.

```
requirejs(["jquery/jquery", "Shared/_MaintenanceTemplateMain", "jquery/jquery-ui", 
"jquery/jquery-ui-layout", "jquery/jquery-ui-blockui", "jquery/jquery.multiselect",
```

Now I am using this master page in one aspx page as `MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/_MaintenanceTemplate.Master"` and in this aspx I have some external js file. While executing this I am getting error like `$ is undefine`.

Answer (score -1):

You can define all your js in main js i.e  **"_MaintenanceTemplateApp.js"** and then you can use in our individual page.

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    paths: {
        // path od your js which you want to use in your individual file.
        jquery: 'jquery-1.9.0'
    }
});
```

Or you can use **"define"** in you individual js

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {...});
```

### **Using require() vs. define()**

We can use both **require()** and **define()** to load dependencies. Understanding the difference between those two functions is essential to managing dependencies. The require() function is used to run immediate functionalities, while define() is used to define modules for use in multiple locations. Mostly require() is used inside main js. However, the other files are reusable modules and therefore use define().

This page have good example with explanation:

https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/

Comment: Master page is inherited from multiple pages and every page has its own js. so, first option is not useful. can you please explain how can i use "define" in detail.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/